# Fiducial based robot relocalization for AMCL

Tags: navigation, ros-kinetic, amcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to use a transform from Fiducial marker to re-localize my odometry on AMCL .

https://github.com/UbiquityRobotics/fiducials , i intend to use this .

1. The idea is to have a fixed fiducial on the map , demarcating the home location
2. Once the fiducial is detected , the robots current position is relocalized based on the tf from the tracker .

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/289444/fiducial-based-robot-relocalization-for-amcl/) by [chrissunny94](https://answers.ros.org/users/33207/chrissunny94/) on ROS Answers with karma: 142 on 2018-04-23

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-04-23**:
What is your question?

**Comment by [chrissunny94](https://answers.ros.org/users/33207/chrissunny94/) on 2018-04-23**:
Once the robot sees a AR_tracker , it should relocalize .

Its kind of like a 'homing' mechanism.

When AMCL starts , it starts at some random coordinate , post which the odometry estimation is often wrong . I want to put in a correction mechanism .

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-04-23**:
Ok, but what is your *question*? You're giving *statements*, but no *question*.

**Comment by [chrissunny94](https://answers.ros.org/users/33207/chrissunny94/) on 2018-04-25**:
@jarvisschultz ,

Thanks solved the problem . I didnt see the inirialpose before .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

One option would be to add use the [initialpose topic](http://wiki.ros.org/amcl#Subscribed_Topics) to completely re-initialize your particle filter whenever you see a known fiducial.

Perhaps a better choice would be to include fiducial measurements into [robot_localization](http://wiki.ros.org/robot_localization) as a measurement source. Then the filtered estimate from `robot_localization` will produce a much more accurate tf tree that `amcl` can use.

---

Originally posted by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) with karma: 9031 on 2018-04-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1